# How to auto Enter y/n and Press Enter key in command prompt using batch or VB script

Tags: batch-file

[image]

Hi,
I want to give auto y/n in command prompt.
And then press Enter key.

Answer (score 1):

In a batch file simply do:

```
C:\temp\Batches>echo y | deinstall.bat
```